# Unity Touch and UI Element works together

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, touch, 2d, platform

I'm making a 2d platform game. I used UI element for shooting and the character moves by touching on screen.

So as to move the character

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.touches.Length>0) {
        Touch firstTouch = Input.GetTouch (0);
        if (firstTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
            if (firstTouch.position.x > ScreenCenterX) {
                sagHareketBasili ();//Move Right
            } 
            if (firstTouch.position.x < ScreenCenterX) {
                solHareketBasili ();//Move Left
            } 
        } else 
            sagHareketBasiliDegil ();//Stop
            solHareketBasiliDegil ();//Stop
        }
    }
}
```

So I made some researches on internet. And I changed my code as

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.touches.Length>0) {
        if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject ()) {
            Touch firstTouch = Input.GetTouch (0);
            if (firstTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
                if (firstTouch.position.x > ScreenCenterX) {
                    sagHareketBasili ();
                } 
                if (firstTouch.position.x < ScreenCenterX) {
                    solHareketBasili ();
                } 
            } else if (firstTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {
                sagHareketBasiliDegil ();
                solHareketBasiliDegil ();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that the problem is solved. But not. 
Firstly, while I'm touching outside of UI elements character moves. if I touch on UI element first time, character moves and UI elements work (both shouldnt work together). If I touch UI element second time I success what I want to do (just UI element works). that is, character doesnt move and UI works fine. 
Secondly, after I touch UI element, if I want character to move and touch outside of UI element, in first touch there is nothing happens, but second and more touches character starts moving as I want.

In UI elements I used Buttons and Event Triggers.

Any help about this please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Input.Touch`, you can create two large transparent buttons one covering left half of screen and other covering right half of screen. And call move left and move right code in OnClick event of each button respectively. As both buttons will be under your usual UI they wont be triggered if you interact with other UI. And set their transparency to 0 so you can see gameplay behind them.

Comment: Thanks much for your answer. I will try it and share the result.